# No scrolling and zooming with touchscreen on X1 carbon gen9

Tags: xubuntu, touchscreen

I installed xubuntu 22.04.1 on a Carbon X1 Gen9 with touchscreen. On the preinstalled windows, I could use the touchscreen to zoom in and and with two fingers on maps.google.com or osm.org. An I think I also could scroll up and down, but both is no longer possible. When trying to zoom just nothing happens and when trying to scroll, I am marking the text instead.

Can I adjust these settings somewhere in xubuntu?

Comment: I did a minimal install of xubuntu 22.04.1 on a Gen6 a few days ago. First device I've had with touchscreen. Out of the box, only single-touch seems to do anything and it duplicates clicking or dragging the left mouse button. I installed `grail-tools` and running `grail-test-atomic` showed that drag and pinch gestures were sometimes recognised. So looks like ought to be possible to do more if one can find the appropriate incantations. All the ubuntu/launchpad/etc webpages on the subject that I've found so far were updated about a decade ago.

Comment: @Jeno, could you update with results for inxi -Fj;lspci;lsusb to give us a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install and configure the drivers and the touch input settings to enable the touchscreen in your device. And in my opinion, it's getting tedious on some devices.

Anyway, here is my solution for a similar screen.

First, make sure you have installed and updated the Xorg input drivers on your device.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Then you will have to configure the setting for your touchscreen input. You can edit the Xorgs configuration file at  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` on some systems).

Find the `Section "InputClass"` block that relates to your touchscreen and add the following settings.

```
Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
```

The `ZAxisMapping` option controls how your touchscreen maps the z-axis (vertical) input to the Xorg server. `4` and `5` means that we map the vertical inputs to the fourth and fifth button events. They are mainly used for scrolling. (You know.. up and down)

On the second line, the `EmulateTwoFingerMinZ` option indicates the minimum z-axis (depth) pressure required to start scrolling with two fingers or zooming. The value `40` corresponds to a pressure of two finger widths.

Once you add these settings to Xorg config file, you will have to restart the Xorg server.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

After that should be able to play with google maps without any issues, but if you encounter "lagging" or miss taps try and play with the values of these options to suit your needs.